# Excluding file extensions from my preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a script I am using to filter some ROM and ISO files.

I have (with a lot of help) got a working script where files are filtered by filename, however I am trying to add a section in which I can include extra ad-hoc filenames to be filtered for me by providing them in a local .txt file. This is working OK, however in my .txt file I am having to put the full filename (including the .txt extension) into the .txt - for example my "manualregiondupes.txt file looks like this:

```
Game One.zip
Game Two.zip
Game Three.zip
```

Whereas I want it to just type them in my .txt file like so:

```
Game One
Game Two
Game Three
```

The current regex i'm using is trying to match the full filename it finds (including the .zip extension) whereas I want it to just match the section before the file extension. I have to be careful, however - as I don't want a game like:

**"Summer Heat Beach Volleyball (USA)"** being matched if **"Beach Volleyball (USA)"** is in the .txt.

Same goes for words on the other side - like

**"Sensible Soccer (USA) (BETA)"** being matched if **"Sensible Soccer (USA)"** is in the .txt

Here is my script;

```
// Make sure what manualregiondupes.txt is doing
if (file_exists('manualregiondupes.txt'))
{
    $manualRegionDupes = file('manualregiondupes.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $manualRegionPattern = "/^(?:" . implode("|", array_map(function ($i)
    {
        return preg_quote(trim($i) , "/");
    }
    , $manualRegionDupes)) . ')$/';
    echo "ManualRegionDupes.txt has been found, ";
    if (trim(file_get_contents('manualregiondupes.txt')) == false)
    {
        echo "but is empty! Continuing without manual region dupes filter.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "and is NOT empty! Applying the manual region dupes filter.\n";
    }
} 
else
{
    echo "ManualRegionDupes.txt has NOT been found. Continuing without the manual region dupes filter.\n"; 
}


        // Do this magic for every file 
    foreach ($gameArray as $thisGame) {
    if (!$thisGame) continue;
    // Probably already been removed
    if (!file_exists($thisGame)) continue;


    // Filenames in manualregiondupes.txt
    if (file_exists('manualregiondupes.txt'))
    {
        if (trim(file_get_contents('manualregiondupes.txt')) == true)
        {
            if (preg_match($manualRegionPattern, $thisGame))
            {
                echo "{$thisGame} is on the manual region dupes remove list. Moved to Removed folder.\n";
                shell_exec("mv \"{$thisGame}\" Removed/");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    ... SCRIPT CONTINUES HERE BUT ISN'T RELEVANT!
```

What's the easiest way of doing this? I think i've just asked a very long question when it's actually quite simple, but oh well - I am not very good with PHP (or any script to be honest!) so apologies and thankyou's in advance! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pathinfo in regex like -

```
$withoutExt = preg_replace('/\.' . preg_quote(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '/') . '$/', '', $path);
```

it gives you perfect file name output without extension for

1. file.txt -> file
2. file.sometext.txt -> file.sometext

Comment: Thanks, how would I add that to my current script? I guess it has to be applied to `$manualDemosPattern`? Sorry I'm a complete beginner!

Comment: Or simply `pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_FILENAME)`

Comment: Hi Michel, so in my case, putting `pathinfo($manualRegionPattern,PATHINFO_FILENAME)` before the `preg_match` might work?

Comment: If you want only the whole filename to match, simply use: `if( $searchstring === pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_FILENAME) ){..}`

Comment: @UnluckyForSome I think you have to use this with a variable where you are getting each filename in loop `$thisGame = preg_replace('/\.' . preg_quote(pathinfo($thisGame, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '/') . '$/', '', $thisGame);` place this code inside foreach loop .

Comment: 1 sec, will try!

Comment: @UnluckyForSome most welcome , please vote the answer if it helped you ...